# Is there a guide to install ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

Is there an idiots guide available that can take me through installing Ubuntu onto my windows 8 laptop right from the start i.e. setting up my flash drive, FAT32, etc please?

Comment: There are videos available on youtube.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need a guide, it's very simple.

All you have to do is this:

First chose the ubuntu you want; there are two; one that's most up to date (ubuntu 13.10) but will be supported for a short time and another that's not the newest version (12.04) but will be supported long. you find those two versions here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop .

I advise you to get 13.10 since it's so easy to upgrade it to the newest version when it's no longer supported.

also chose 32bit or 64bit according to your computer's specs.

then follow this guide to create the bootable USB http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Then shut down your computer, plug in the USB, start your computer, look carefully at the screen; there should be a button to press so that you choose what device you want to boot the computer from (you want to boot it from the USB you've just created). It's usually DEL button or F12. you should see for example "F12 Boot Options" right when your computer starts.

When you press the correct button you should be presented with options. Chose your USB. (find some clue; maybe part of its name will be displayed) and don't worry if you chose a wrong option, nothing will happen, be brave.

Then if you do the previous correctly Ubuntu should start! then a window will appear with two buttons; try ubuntu and install ubuntu. It's better to try ubuntu first so that you make sure that it's working with your computer. And to setup your internet connection.

If you're good with all the previous then you can follow this link http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest

feed me back ;)

Answer (score 0):

First download the latest Ubuntu release from this link :[Get Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
You can choose between two versions : **64-bit** or **32-bit**
To find whether your computer has got either 64-bit or 32-bit refer this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827218).
Now you got the ISO image of the Ubuntu.
In order to make bootable USB of this image, I recommend the software [LiLi](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://www.linuxliveusb.com/&ei=Wy-sUrrLKsWOrQfwuoDwCw&usg=AFQjCNGHi-98clOd_uDJInMlbh4p2Xb4bw&sig2=mC9XrirPkVkQI2nD_NkKfQ&bvm=bv.57967247,d.bmk). It will make the process very simple.  Now restart the computer press the appropriate button (F12) most probably to get the Bootable devices and boot from the USB.
Now refer the follwing link to get step by step installation guide : [Install Ubuntu](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/step-by-step-beginners-guide-to-installing-ubuntu-11-10.172128/)